# Amazon AWS machines are not connecting

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, mpi, mpich

I have an Amazon AWS account, I have created 4 machines, but in security groups there is no option for outbound, therefore, when I send a ping request it is not forwarding.
Any help will be appreciated, how can I connect my machines, I am implementing an MPICH2 cluster.

Comment: Please elaborate on the direction of the ping.

Comment: There is no direction their, host unreachable etc, nothing, just i ping and system remains constant until I press Ctrl+z

Comment: Please tell me whether you try to ping the EC2 instance from the outside or whether you try to ping an outside host from the EC2 instances.

Comment: from an EC2 instance to another EC2 instance

Comment: Did you use the internal or the external IP?

Comment: private IP, but it does not matters, i think you are not getting the problem, it does not matters on which IP you are sending ping, both replies, or at least send some messages, the problem is with security group it is not showing outbound

Comment: To ease reproduction of the problem you always should provide as much information as possible.  Your question lacked a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable ICMP on your security groups.

Check below:

[image: Security Groups]